# Android 4.1.2 and geocoder

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, google-geocoder

I need to use google geocoder to display an address from gps coordinates in my app.

The fact is that I get an error like : "unable to parse response from the server" in my app.

It seems, after some documentation, that it's due to Android 4.1.2.

**Question**

I need to know, if there was any way to encounter this and get addresses from gps coordinates ?

Here's my actual code that throw me the error :

```
public String[] reverseGeocoding(Double latitude, Double longitude) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    String[] adress = new String[3];
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        Log.e("ADRESSE SIZE", addresses.size() + "");
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);

            adress[0] = address.getAddressLine(0);
            adress[1] = address.getLocality();
            adress[2] = address.getPostalCode();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        adress[0] = adress[1] = adress[2] = null;
    }

    return adress;
}
```

Comment: Does the error just encounter on Android 4.1.2? Did you try another API such that Android L?

Comment: In L, Kitkat and 4.3 it s working. (We need only api 4+)

Comment: For the specific android version bug, you can report the issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:Android2%20type:Defect&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars), the engineers from Google may help.